# Visualizing a multiple parameter integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I'm really new to Mathematica and all the other answers to similar questions don't seem to help me. I have an integral I'd like to solve, and I'm having problems. My integral looks like this:

$\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\frac{\gamma\beta}{r^3}[3\cos{\theta}\cos{\theta'}-\cos{(\theta-\theta')}]} d\theta'$

where all other parameters should be free to change after the integration. My attempt in Mathematica was this:

```
funct[theta0_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ, beta_?NumericQ, gamma_?NumericQ] := 
   NIntegrate[
     Exp[(beta*gamma/r^3)*(3*Cos[theta]*Cos[theta0] - Cos[theta0 - theta])], 
     {theta, 0, Pi}]
```

I'm not even sure if it's working or not. What should this even return? Eventually I'd like to plot the function in the $(r,\,\theta)$ plane with $\gamma$ and $\beta$ free to change for the user. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
  tbl = 
    Flatten[
     Table[{θ0, r, funct[θ0, r, β, γ]}, {θ0, 1, 10, 0.5}, {r, 1, 10, 0.5}],  
     1];
   ListPlot3D[tbl, AxesLabel -> {θ, r, v}, PlotRange -> All],
   {β, -2, 2, 0.1},
   {γ, -2, 2, 0.1}]
```

[image]